# How do I reset Spring Kafka Offset with a rest end point

Tags: spring-kafka

I want a rest end point for replaying messages in case of any issues.

1. Pause the Kafka container .
2. Reset the Offset for a particular partition/topic .
3. Resume the Kafka Container

How can I call seek() in Consumer and  pass partition/topic .Below is the controller

```
    @GetMapping("/KafkaConsumerMaintainence")
        public void pause(  )
        {
            
    
            kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("foo").pause();
            
            // seek the offset here 
            
            kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("foo").resume();
            
            
        }

@Service
public class KafKaConsumerService extends  AbstractConsumerSeekAware
    @KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = "mytopic-3", concurrency = "3", groupId = "mytopic-1-groupid")
        public void consumeFromTopic1(@Payload @Valid Foo message, ConsumerRecordMetadata c)  {
    
            dbservice.processInDB(message);
        }
//not able to pass offset
public void seekToOffset(TopicPartition topicPartition) {
        getSeekCallbackFor(topicPartition);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what your problem is, simply do this...

```java
public void seekToOffset(TopicPartition tp, long offset) {
    getSeekCallbackFor(topicPartition).seek(tp.topic(), tp.partition(), offset);
}
```

Comment: I had solved it .Thanks `public void seekToAnOffset(int partition,long offset,String topic) {
  super.getSeekCallbackFor(new TopicPartition(topic,partition)).seek(topic, partition, offset);
 }`

Comment: @Gary , * tp.partition()